# Show to see the percentage of each points for each cluster in DBSCAN?

Tags: python, dbscan

I am trying to find the percentage of each point to each cluster in DBSCAN model. For example, Hokkaido city belongs 80% to the first cluster, 15% to the second cluster, and 5% to the third cJust like the Fuzzy C-means model.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I didn't understand

Comment: The normal dbscan algorithm does not support this. Look into 'fuzzy dbscan' instead. There are some github repositories available but I haven't used any of them though so not sure which is the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using hdbscan, which is similar to dbscan, according to the [manual](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_hdbscan_works.html):

> [HDBSCAN] extends DBSCAN by converting it into a hierarchical
> clustering algorithm, and then using a technique to extract a flat
> clustering based in the stability of clusters.

There is an option to do [soft clustering](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soft_clustering_explanation.html):

```
import hdbscan
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=3, n_features=2,random_state=0,cluster_std=0.7)

clus = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=15,prediction_data=True).fit(X)

sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1],hue=clus.labels_)
```

[image]

Then you get the probabilities (1st column is for cluster '0', 2nd cluster '1' and so on) which you can check against the labels:

```
prob = hdbscan.all_points_membership_vectors(clus)

array([[4.88979537e-002, 5.80273190e-001, 9.26444109e-002],
       [4.85037364e-001, 6.25797263e-002, 6.64264496e-002],
       [4.12816307e-002, 8.05701839e-001, 5.20814550e-002],
       [3.21243913e-309, 5.88566049e-309, 1.00000000e+000],
       [6.50419242e-002, 8.72702527e-002, 5.57944199e-001]])

clus.labels_[:5]

array([1, 0, 1, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I need a table like below. Hokkaido : cluster 1(%90), cluster 2(5%), cluster 3 (5%)--- tokoshima : cluster 1 (%50), cluster 2 (%30), cluster 3(%20) and so on.

Comment: if you read the last part of my answer, you can see that it gives you exactly that probability. can you provide your dataset? otherwise no one can help u